# How to identify bots traffic in Google Analytics BigQuery data?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm querying BigQuery tables that underneath GoogleAnalytics to get unique visitors, I need to filter out bots traffic, so my question come to that how to identify bots in those tables? I was looking at the fields such as "trafficSource.source" and "trafficSource.medium" with filters like "where trafficSource.medium='(none)' " but not sure this is the right way, can anyone knows better about this?